# How to install libguestfs-tools 1.26 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, virtualization

Default version of `libguestfs-tools` for `Ubuntu 12.04` is 1.14 but I want to install the newer version ( 1.26 ). Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky, but possible.  You will need to [carefully follow the instructions in the FAQ entry here](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#how-can-i-compile-and-install-libguestfs-if-my-distro-doesnt-have-new-enough-qemu-supermin-kernel).  You will need to build supermin version 5 first.

Comment: I have installed latest `supermin`  (5) from source on Ubuntu, but there is no `supermin-helper` that is now present. When I run `virt-cat` it looks for `supermin-helper`. From the man pages and sources, I see that now `--build` option has superseded `supermin-helper`. But `virt-cat` seems to be invoking something like `-f checksum --host-cpu x86_64 /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d`. Is there any way to do the same with `supermin` ?